# How to check for a new session in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check for a new session in aspx page? And what is the difference between below three lines of checking session

```
1. if (Session["DETAILS"] == null) 
2. if (Session["DETAILS"] == "")
3. if (Session["DETAILS"].ToString() == "new")
```

Please help me how to check session in a page load event of aspx page. So I need that if session is new I need to enter new values. If session is edit I need to edit the values already present .

Answer (score 0):

The first two `if` statements are checking if a session value identified by key `DETAILS` is stored in current session.

The third might throw a `NullReferenceException` when the object with given key is not stored in session and the call results in `null` reference. This is not safe.

If I get it right, the session is "new" when the key is not in session. It also depends on the type of the value, so for `string` the code might look like

```
var sessionValue = SESSION["DETAILS"];
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionValue))
{
   // session is "new", i.e. the value was not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 'New Session', you mean checking if the session is empty, then use

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(Session["Obj"].toString())) //This will return true or false
{
   //Do this if true
}
else
{
   //Do this if false
   //Below will force the session to be cleared
   Session.Abandon();
   Session.Clear();
   Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); //Which will reload the current page
}
```

`if (Session["DETAILS"]== null)` checks if the session is null,
`if (Session["DETAILS"]== "")` checks if the session string is empty,

**Note that the above two can be replaced with** `string.isNullOrEmpty(Session["Obj"].toString());`

`if (Session["DETAILS"].tostring()== "new")` checks if the session equals the correlating string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Session["DETAILS"]== null)
```

***Is used to check for existence of a session. (If the session exist or not)***

```
if (Session["DETAILS"]== "")
```

***Is used to check If the session is empty (Doesn't contains any value.)***

```
if (Session["DETAILS"].tostring()== "new")
```

***Is used to compare the Session value with other value (In this case => "new")***

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the events in the Global.asx especially the Session_Start and Session_End events:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["DETAILS"] != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["DETAILS"] = "[type here your data]";
    }
}
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful

```
Session.IsNewSession
```

more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.isnewsession.aspx

and for the explanation you have got so  many answers and @kakarott's is precise and small